# UI Automation changing property IsEnabled Property Element

Tags: wpf, microsoft-ui-automation

We are running a custom process injection into a WPF Process, and enable named pipe between process to communicate.  I want to disable the mainwindows until I complete my injection process.

I am using UIAutomation Libraries to check wpf window properties.  `AutomationElement` gives a method to check property value via `GetCurrentValue` of the property.

What is the equivalent of the `SetCurrentValue` method so that I can set the `IsEnabledProperty`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there isn't a ControlPattern that allows you to disable a control. Keep in mind that the UIAutomation library is primarily intended for black-box style testing, so there isn't much capability in there that interacts with controls in ways an end user wouldn't be able to.

If the UIA library is your only means of performing this test, you might want to investigate [custom control patterns](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winuiautomation/archive/2010/12/08/uia-custom-patterns-part-1.aspx) as a possible means of getting around it. The downside here is that it violates black-box principles to some extent, and will mean additional work for the developers.